# Unable to connect to postgres database on unix server.(works fine when connected through PuTTy Tunnel)

Tags: linux, postgresql, pentaho, putty, postgresql-9.3

While trying to connect Pentaho spoon (DB Connection) to Postgres database on
linux server I get the error:

> Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the
> postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Here are my pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files:

[pg_hba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ne3o.jpg)

[postgres.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3BlB.jpg)

Note: I am able to connect through PuTTy

Postgresql is on version 9.3 on the server

Comment: `ipfw` or `iptables`?.. an please better paste the whole string from `hba.conf`, not just I did md5 and all hosts

Comment: this community is about **programming**, not server help.